# Scale and concatenate pandas dataframe into a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I have a fairly large pandas dataframe `df`. I also have a pandas series of scale factors `factors`.

I want to scale `df` for every scale factor in `factors` and concatenate these dataframes together into a larger dataframe. Since this large dataframe will not fit into memory, I thought it may be good to use dask dataframe for the same. But I dont know how to get around this problem.

Below is what i want to achieve, but using pandas dataframes. The `dflarge` in the actual case will not fit in memory.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id1': range(1,6), 
        'a': [random.random() for i in range(5)], 
        'b': [random.random() for i in range(5)],
    })
df = df.set_index('id1')

factors = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

dflist = []

for i, factor in enumerate(factors):
    scaled = df*factor
    scaled['id2'] = i
    dflist.append(scaled)

dflarge = pd.concat(dflist)
dflarge = dflarge.reset_index().set_index(['id1', 'id2'])
```

I would like to make the scaling and concatenating as efficient as possible since there will be tens of thousands of scale factors. I'd like to run it distributed if possible.

I really appreciate any kind of help you can give.

Comment: Do you mind to define large?

Comment: @rpanai The corresponding csv file would be of the order of 1GB to 3GB.

Answer (score 2):

***Just delay it!***

`Dask.dataframe` and `dask.delayed` are what you need here, and running it using `dask.distributed`should work fine. Assuming that `df` is still a `pandas.DataFrame`, turn the loop into a function that you can call in a list comprehension using `dask.delayed`. I've made some small changes to your code below:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id1': range(1,6), 
        'a': [random.random() for i in range(5)], 
        'b': [random.random() for i in range(5)],
    })
df = df.set_index('id1')

factors = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

dflist = []

def scale_my_df(df_init, scale_factor, id_num):
    '''
    Scales and returns a DataFrame.
    '''
    df_scaled = df_init * scale_factor
    df_scaled['id2'] = id_num
    return df_scaled

dfs_delayed = [delayed(scale_my_df)(df_init=df, scale_factor=factor, id_num=i) 
               for i, factor in enumerate(factors)]
ddf = dd.from_delayed(dfs_delayed)
```

And now you have a `dask.DataFrame` built from your scaled `pandas.DataFrame`s. Two things of note:

1. `Dask` is lazy, so as of the end of this code snippet nothing has been computed. A computational graph has been setup with the required operations to create the DataFrame you want. In this example with small DataFrames, you could execute:

   `ddf_large = ddf.compute()`

And you will have the same `pandas.DataFrame` as `dflarge` in your code above, assuming the `factors` are the same. Almost...

2. As of this writing `dask` does not appear to support multi-level indices, so your `.set_index(['id1', 'id2'])` code will not work. This has been raised in [issue #1493](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1493) and there are some workarounds if you really need a multi-level index.

EDIT:

3. If the original data `df` is really large, as in already maxing your memory, converting it to a `.csv`or other `pandas`-readable format, and build that into the scale function might be necessary, i.e:

```
    def scale_my_df(df_filepath, scale_factor, id_num):
        '''
        Scales and returns a DataFrame.
        '''
        df_init = pd.read_csv(df_filepath)
        df_scaled = df_init * scale_factor
        df_scaled['id2'] = id_num
        return df_scaled
```

And adjust the rest of the code accordingly. The idea of `dask` is to keep the data out of memory, but there is some overhead involved with building the computational graph and holding intermediate values.

Comment: If `ddf_large` doesn't fit in memory this approach could return a `Memory Error` and if instead of compute you save to parquets as `ddf.to_parquet("data/")` you are going to have as much files as the factors you have. Maybe will be better to save to disk every iteration.

Comment: @rpanai This is true, which is why I said "In this example with small DataFrames", and even then it is only to view and compare the values in the result to that of the `pandas.DataFrame` in the original question. Obviously calling `.compute()` on a `dask.DataFrame` defeats the purpose of using `dask` in the first place.

Comment: The ultimate aim is to write it out in a custom format which looks more like a groupby object, which is grouped by `id1`.